# Can I attach an EC2 instance to an existing Load Balancer using CloudFormation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

The way we usually attach instances to a Load Balancer is by using the instances key while defining the load balancer in my aws template. Is there anyway that I can attach an EC2 instance to a Load Balancer that already exists?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you don't mind creating the EC2 instance indirectly through an [`AWS::AutoScaling::AutoScalingGroup`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-as-group.html) (e.g., with a [`DesiredCapacity`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-as-group.html#cfn-as-group-desiredcapacity) of **1**), you could automatically attach the EC2 instance to an existing ELB using the [`LoadBalancerNames`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-as-group.html#cfn-as-group-loadbalancernames) (or [`TargetGroupARNs`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-as-group.html#cfn-as-group-targetgrouparns) if using an Application Load Balancer) property.

Otherwise, you can call the [`RegisterInstancesWithLoadBalancer`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/2012-06-01/APIReference/API_RegisterInstancesWithLoadBalancer.html) / [`DeregisterInstancesFromLoadBalancer`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/2012-06-01/APIReference/API_DeregisterInstancesFromLoadBalancer.html) APIs manually, either directly from the EC2 instance (e.g., from a [`UserData`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-instance.html#cfn-ec2-instance-userdata) script using the AWS CLI), or using a [Custom Resource](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-custom-resources.html) (e.g., using the AWS SDK for JavaScript from a Lambda function).